# Spring - How do I test the arguments received by a method that is called by another method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Some clarification,
I am calling the emitObject() method. I would like to verify the following:

- that someMethod() gets called,
- that anotherObject() is created successfully
- the values passed to anotherObject() constructor

```
public void emitObject(CustomObject customObject1, CustomObject customObject2) {

    someMethod(new anotherObject(
      customObject1.someProp1,
      customObject1.someProp2,
      customObject2.someProp1,
      customObject2.someProp2,
    ));

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to verify that? If this wouldn't work Java would be broken. Apart from that a unit test is testing a unit not it's interanal

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The test I described doesnt make sense to me either, it was a requirement by one of my senior devs. To my understanding, if there is a test for someMethod() and the test proves that the method works, then we should be able to assume that emitObject() would also work as expected?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the point. One other thing is that a method that doesn't return anything and probably changes the internal state is not suitable for testing. It's much better to have a functional style programming model

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thank you very much, this cleared up my confusion